# Override callback from a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, namespaces, scope, overriding

Is it possible to override a callback inside a function?

```
function fn() {
    function cb() {
        console.log("Overriden");
    }
}

function cb() {
    console.log("Original");
}
```

As far as I understand, the cb inside the fn becomes a local variable. Hence, when any other functions call cb, they will still get the original function. Is there a way to override the callback?

Edit: Below is the actual code.

```
module.exports = function(app, passport, async) {

    var isLoggedIn = function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.isAuthenticated())
             return next();
        res.redirect('/');
    };

    app.get('/info', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {              
        res.render('info.ejs', {message: req.flash('loginMessage')});
    });

    app.post('/add', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        process.nextTick(function() {            
            // do something here
            isLoggedIn = function(req, res, next) {
                console.log("Modified"); 
            }; 
            res.redirect('/info');
        });         
    });
}
```

Comment: there is no variable inside fn

Comment: Actually there is no _callback_.

Comment: It is a callback for another function. Not for the fn, specifically.

Comment: are you saying the cb function is overriding the cb inside fn

Comment: Yes, this is what I see.

Comment: Maybe you mean `cb = function() {...}` . However there is probably a better solution. You are not giving a lot of context.

Answer (score 0):

The `cb` function in the context of the `fn` function is a local function that can only be called within that context. So if you call the `fn` function and then the `cb`, ie. `fn(); cb();`, then the global `cb` will be called not the local `cb`.

A callback is a function that is passed as an argument to another function and it's executed when an operation is complete. So your code probably should be:

```
function fn(callback) {
    // do something
    if (typeof callback === 'function') {
        callback();
    } else {
       cb();
    }
}

function cb() {
    console.log("Original");
}

fn(); // "Original"

fn(function() {
    console.log("Overriden");
}); // "Overriden"
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. Inside the fn, the function cb is overridden. However, outside of it, it is not. I never meant, though, that the cb is a callback of fn. It's a callback for another function, that I didn't specify in the example (maybe I should have). But my purpose is to override the cb dynamically from the fn. Even if fn doesn't directly call the cb. So that when other functions call the callback, they will get an overridden function.

Comment: @elena Well, if you want to override the original function you can code: `cb = callback;`  or if it's a global function `window.cb = callback`.

Comment: I would think that this should work, but for some reason it doesn't. The callback is still the same as before. Also, I have to mention that this is server side code.

Comment: @elena Does that mean that the environment is Node.js? Please check this http://jsfiddle.net/9qhu63a9/

Comment: Yes, the environment is Node.js. It seems to work in the example you provided. I guess there's something going on in my own code.

Comment: I was wondering if functions can remember references to previously called callbacks? I change the callback after the functions have already called the callback previously. It doesn't seem to change their previous callback to the new one.

Comment: @elena No, functions do not do that. You are overwriting the function on run-time, after overwriting, the old function is replaced with the new one. I don't know what you really call a callback function though. It would be helpful if your could  post the _actual_ code in your question. Please check https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope

Comment: I've updated my question. Could you please take a look.

Comment: @elena Sure. So you want to replace the `isLoggedIn` function after it has been executed? The function is a `filter` for a route, yes? You can't do that. As a suggestion, you should move the logic to the original function, probably using an `if` statement!

Comment: Indeed, the function is a filter. So there's no way to replace it after it has been executed?

Comment: @elena You are currently replacing it. What's the point of doing this after executing the filter?

Comment: Either I understand something wrong, or something else is going on. The filter is executed several times, not just once. So I want to change its behavior at a particular moment in time.

Comment: @elena Why don't you use a flag? Store something in DB/Sesstion? Usually when you find yourself overriding a function you are doing something wrong. There should be only one function that handles a specific task.